# When using the GCC driver, what makes a static lib "incompatible"?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, musl

So what I am trying to do is on Ubuntu 14.04 (x86_64) I want to set up `musl-libc` based on the latest released 1.1.11 version which is available at this moment.

What I did was to:

1. Install multilib support for GCC: `sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install gcc-multilib`
2. Configure the libraries for 32-bit and 64-bit respectively and install them into separate folders:

   - `CFLAGS=-m32 ./configure --prefix=$HOME/bin/musl-32-bit --disable-shared --target=i386-linux-gnu && make && make install`
   - `CFLAGS=-m64 ./configure --prefix=$HOME/bin/musl-64-bit --disable-shared --target=x86_64-linux-gnu`

Then in order to build a statically linked `premake4`, I invoke GNU make like this on the `Makefile` generated by `premake4`:

```
make -j 8 CC=$HOME/bin/musl-32-bit/bin/musl-gcc ARCH=-m32 LDFLAGS="-v -static" verbose=1
```

This appears to work up to the linking step, which bombs with:

```
Linking Premake4
$HOME/bin/musl-32-bit/bin/musl-gcc -o bin/release/premake4 intermediate/gmake__/premake.o intermediate/gmake__/os_uuid.o intermediate/gmake__/os_pathsearch.o intermediate/gmake__/os_match.o intermediate/gmake__/os_chdir.o intermediate/gmake__/os_mkdir.o intermediate/gmake__/os_stat.o intermediate/gmake__/os_getversion.o intermediate/gmake__/premake_main.o intermediate/gmake__/os_isdir.o intermediate/gmake__/string_endswith.o intermediate/gmake__/os_isfile.o intermediate/gmake__/scripts.o intermediate/gmake__/path_isabsolute.o intermediate/gmake__/os_rmdir.o intermediate/gmake__/os_getcwd.o intermediate/gmake__/os_is64bit.o intermediate/gmake__/os_copyfile.o intermediate/gmake__/lstate.o intermediate/gmake__/ltable.o intermediate/gmake__/lgc.o intermediate/gmake__/lobject.o intermediate/gmake__/lcode.o intermediate/gmake__/lmathlib.o intermediate/gmake__/lbaselib.o intermediate/gmake__/lmem.o intermediate/gmake__/lfunc.o intermediate/gmake__/lparser.o intermediate/gmake__/ldblib.o intermediate/gmake__/lzio.o intermediate/gmake__/lstrlib.o intermediate/gmake__/lvm.o intermediate/gmake__/lauxlib.o intermediate/gmake__/llex.o intermediate/gmake__/lstring.o intermediate/gmake__/ldump.o intermediate/gmake__/ldebug.o intermediate/gmake__/loadlib.o intermediate/gmake__/lopcodes.o intermediate/gmake__/linit.o intermediate/gmake__/ldo.o intermediate/gmake__/lapi.o intermediate/gmake__/liolib.o intermediate/gmake__/loslib.o intermediate/gmake__/lundump.o intermediate/gmake__/ltm.o intermediate/gmake__/ltablib.o    -v -static -L. -s -rdynamic  -lm -ldl
Using built-in specs.
Reading specs from $HOME/bin/musl-32-bit/lib/musl-gcc.specs
rename spec cpp_options to old_cpp_options
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib32/:/lib/../lib32/:/usr/lib/../lib32/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-m32' '-o' 'bin/release/premake4' '-v' '-static' '-L.' '-s' '-rdynamic' '-specs=$HOME/bin/musl-32-bit/lib/musl-gcc.specs' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i686'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/collect2 -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-musl-i386.so.1 -nostdlib -static -export-dynamic -z relro -o bin/release/premake4 -s $HOME/bin/musl-32-bit/lib/crt1.o $HOME/bin/musl-32-bit/lib/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtbegin.o -L. -L$HOME/bin/musl-32-bit/lib -L /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/. intermediate/gmake__/premake.o intermediate/gmake__/os_uuid.o intermediate/gmake__/os_pathsearch.o intermediate/gmake__/os_match.o intermediate/gmake__/os_chdir.o intermediate/gmake__/os_mkdir.o intermediate/gmake__/os_stat.o intermediate/gmake__/os_getversion.o intermediate/gmake__/premake_main.o intermediate/gmake__/os_isdir.o intermediate/gmake__/string_endswith.o intermediate/gmake__/os_isfile.o intermediate/gmake__/scripts.o intermediate/gmake__/path_isabsolute.o intermediate/gmake__/os_rmdir.o intermediate/gmake__/os_getcwd.o intermediate/gmake__/os_is64bit.o intermediate/gmake__/os_copyfile.o intermediate/gmake__/lstate.o intermediate/gmake__/ltable.o intermediate/gmake__/lgc.o intermediate/gmake__/lobject.o intermediate/gmake__/lcode.o intermediate/gmake__/lmathlib.o intermediate/gmake__/lbaselib.o intermediate/gmake__/lmem.o intermediate/gmake__/lfunc.o intermediate/gmake__/lparser.o intermediate/gmake__/ldblib.o intermediate/gmake__/lzio.o intermediate/gmake__/lstrlib.o intermediate/gmake__/lvm.o intermediate/gmake__/lauxlib.o intermediate/gmake__/llex.o intermediate/gmake__/lstring.o intermediate/gmake__/ldump.o intermediate/gmake__/ldebug.o intermediate/gmake__/loadlib.o intermediate/gmake__/lopcodes.o intermediate/gmake__/linit.o intermediate/gmake__/ldo.o intermediate/gmake__/lapi.o intermediate/gmake__/liolib.o intermediate/gmake__/loslib.o intermediate/gmake__/lundump.o intermediate/gmake__/ltm.o intermediate/gmake__/ltablib.o -lm -ldl --start-group /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc.a /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc_eh.a -lc --end-group /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtend.o $HOME/bin/musl-32-bit/lib/crtn.o
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible $HOME/bin/musl-32-bit/lib/libc.a when searching for -lc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [bin/release/premake4] Error 1
make: *** [Premake4] Error 2
```

The relevant line is:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible $HOME/bin/musl-32-bit/lib/libc.a when searching for -lc
```

Now the part I don't understand about this is, that when I `ar x` the `libc.a` (into a folder `$HOME/bin/musl-32-bit/lib/libc`) generated during the build step of `musl-libc` (see above), it proves that all of the objects included seem to be of the correct target architecture (all show `ELF 32-bit LSB  relocatable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped`) as I can prove from coming up empty when issuing the following command:

```
find $HOME/bin/musl-32-bit/lib -name '*.o' -exec file {} +|grep -v 'ELF 32-bit LSB  relocatable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped'
```

And in fact this gives no output. Similarly when looking inside the build directory using the same method, I cannot find any object file that doesn't match my expectation.

For good measure I decided to also task `objdump` to tell me more about the `libc.a` in question and came up with the same result:

```
objdump -a $HOME/bin/musl-32-bit/lib/libc.a|grep 'file format'|grep -v 'file format elf32-i386'
```

So my question is twofold:

1. what disqualifies a static library as "incompatible" when GCC is asked to link it?
2. what could be the particular issue I am seeing?

The first is what I am really interested in, but with the second I am asking to share your experience with trouble-shooting like this. Which verification steps have I missed, for example?

---

Please note that the "native" `premake4` builds just fine with:

```
make -j 8 CC=$HOME/bin/musl-64-bit/bin/musl-gcc ARCH=-m64 LDFLAGS=-static verbose=1
```

From the output when adding the `-v` flag to `LDFLAGS` it appears as if the target always stays at `x86_64-linux-gnu`. I have yet to come up with a method to fix this, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The solution

It turns out the solution is rather simple.

We need to tell both the linker and the driver to use `-m32` ... I was that far before. However, it turns out that the missing piece was to pass the linker option to the driver via `CFLAGS` like this `-Wl,-melf_i386`.

I am finally able to build and link the 32-bit executable on a multilib-enabled 64-bit host.

---

**NB:** Below information is left in place for those who want to learn how I investigated the issue.

Alright, so I investigated the issue a little further and the output gets more enlightening once you extract the object files. To reproduce what I am doing you may have to use Bash or a similar shell that allows for `$(...)` or you need to adjust the command lines accordingly.

First off it's important to have `gcc-multilib` and friends installed in order to target `-m32` (`i386-linux-gnu` which happens to be an alias for `i686-linux-gnu` here).

### The code and the make file

I had the following make file:

```
CC?=$(HOME)/bin/musl/bin64/musl-gcc
BLDARCH?=-m64
CFLAGS+=-v $(BLDARCH)
LDFLAGS+=-v -static $(BLDARCH)

all: helloworld

helloworld: helloworld.c

clean:
    rm -f helloworld

rebuild: clean all

.PHONY: clean rebuild
.NOTPARALLEL: rebuild
```

and the following small `helloworld.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and my 32-bit musl-libc was installed to `$HOME/bin/musl/{bin,include,lib}32` respectively. The 64-bit one was installed to `$HOME/bin/musl/{bin,include,lib}64` respectively.

Attempting to build with:

```
make CC=$HOME/bin/musl/bin32/musl-gcc BLDARCH=-m32 rebuild
```

always failed with the same meaningless lines:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ~/bin/musl/lib32/libc.a when searching for -lc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [helloworld] Error 1
```

### Digging into the details

So after some contemplation I decided to re-do the steps done by the `gcc` driver manually.

This meant to run roughly (I replaced all occurrences of my home folder with a `~`):

- Compile: `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/cc1 -quiet -imultilib 32 -imultiarch i386-linux-gnu helloworld.c -nostdinc -isystem ~/bin/musl/include32 -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include -quiet -dumpbase helloworld.c -m32 -mtune=generic -march=i686 -auxbase helloworld -version -fstack-protector -Wformat -Wformat-security -o /tmp/ccGmMuR1.s`
- Assemble: `as -v -v --32 -o /tmp/ccgRGlqf.o /tmp/ccGmMuR1.s`
- Link: `env COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/ LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/32/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib32/:/lib/../lib32/:/usr/lib/../lib32/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/ COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS="-v -v -static -m32 -o helloworld -specs=~/bin/musl/lib32/musl-gcc.specs -mtune=generic -march=i686" /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/collect2 -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-musl-i386.so.1 -nostdlib -static -z relro -o helloworld ~/bin/musl/lib32/crt1.o ~/bin/musl/lib32/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/32/crtbegin.o -L~/bin/musl/lib32 -L /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/32/. /tmp/ccpL09mJ.o --start-group /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/32/libgcc.a /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/32/libgcc_eh.a -lc --end-group /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/32/crtend.o ~/bin/musl/lib32/crtn.o`

Obviously this didn't change the error message a bit just yet:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ~/bin/musl/lib32/libc.a when searching for -lc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So I took out the `-lc` from the command line for `collect2` and created a folder `~/bin/musl/lib32/archive` into which I extracted the whole `libc.a` generated by my musl-libc build attempt. I then instructed `collect2` where to find the object files like this:

Link: `env COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/ LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gc
c/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/32/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib32/:/lib/../lib32/:/usr/lib/../lib32/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/ COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS="-v -v -
static -m32 -o helloworld -specs=~/bin/musl/lib32/musl-gcc.specs -mtune=generic -march=i686" /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/collect2 -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-musl-i386.so.1 -nostdlib -static -z relro -o helloworld $HOME/bin/musl/lib32/crt1.o ~/bin/musl/lib32/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/32/crtbegin.o -L~/bin/musl/lib32 -L /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/32/. /tmp/ccpL09mJ.o --start-group /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-g
nu/4.8/32/libgcc.a /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/32/libgcc_eh.a --end-group /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/32/crtend.o ~/bin/musl/lib32/crtn.o $(find ~/bin/musl/lib32/archive -type f -name '*.o')`

This gist is taking out `-lc` and appending `$(find ~/bin/musl/lib32/archive -type f -name '*.o')`.

Which gave me a whole bunch of new, but more meaningful errors similar to the following ones:

```
/usr/bin/ld: Warning: size of symbol `__init_ssp' changed from 1 in ~/bin/musl/lib32/archive/__libc_start_main.o to 65 in ~/bin/musl/lib32/archive/__stack_chk_fail.o
/usr/bin/ld: Warning: size of symbol `__funcs_on_exit' changed from 126 in ~/bin/musl/lib32/archive/atexit.o to 1 in ~/bin/musl/lib32/archive/exit.o
# more of those
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `~/bin/musl/lib32/crt1.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `~/bin/musl/lib32/crti.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
# more of those
```

The plot thickens. Apparently the `collect2` command gets the wrong idea about what to build. Which is odd considering the output for the governing environment variables:

```
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/32/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib32/:/lib/../lib32/:/usr/lib/../lib32/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-v' '-static' '-m32' '-o' 'helloworld' '-specs=~/bin/musl/lib32/musl-gcc.specs' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i686'
```

... which I passed using `env` in my attempt to reproduce the conditions encountered by the `collect2` wrapper when linking the `libc.a`.

In order to find out more about the internals of the GNU compilers one needs to read https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/

Unfortunately the part about `collect2` doesn't help us here. But the lengthy output of `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/collect2 --help` looks promising.

Just how could we smuggle our command line option to `collect2`?

For now I was going to settle for whatever I could run manually. So I attempted to tell the linker which output format I expected. Based on the list of supported targets I was interested in `elf_i386`.

Passing `-melf_386` at the end of the previous line gave an interesting error output. Numerous referenced functions such as `__vsyscall`, `__moddi3` and `__divdi3` were undefined. That indicated they simply didn't exist in the object files from the static lib or in any of the startup `.o` files for that matter:

```
~/bin/musl/lib32/archive/aio.o: In function `cleanup':
aio.c:(.text+0x5ad): undefined reference to `__vsyscall'
aio.c:(.text+0x5bb): undefined reference to `__vsyscall'
aio.c:(.text+0x5e8): undefined reference to `__vsyscall'
aio.c:(.text+0x5f6): undefined reference to `__vsyscall'
aio.c:(.text+0x61d): undefined reference to `__vsyscall'
~/bin/musl/lib32/archive/aio.o:aio.c:(.text+0x62b): more undefined references to `__vsyscall' follow
~/bin/musl/lib32/archive/cpow.o: In function `cpow':
cpow.c:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `__mulxc3'
~/bin/musl/lib32/archive/cpowf.o: In function `cpowf':
cpowf.c:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `__mulxc3'
~/bin/musl/lib32/archive/cpowl.o: In function `cpowl':
cpowl.c:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `__mulxc3'
~/bin/musl/lib32/archive/sysconf.o: In function `sysconf':
sysconf.c:(.text+0xcc): undefined reference to `__vsyscall'
~/bin/musl/lib32/archive/__getdents.o: In function `__getdents':
__getdents.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `__vsyscall'
~/bin/musl/lib32/archive/opendir.o: In function `opendir':
opendir.c:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `__vsyscall'
~/bin/musl/lib32/archive/readdir.o: In function `readdir':
readdir.c:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `__vsyscall'
~/bin/musl/lib32/archive/__init_tls.o: In function `__init_tls':
__init_tls.c:(.text+0x136): undefined reference to `__vsyscall6'
__init_tls.c:(.text+0x16e): undefined reference to `__vsyscall'
```

As I had already clarified in my *question*, the object files from the archive all stated that they were `elf32-i386`.

The functions `__vsyscall` and `__vsyscall6` should end up in a file called `syscall.o` given the source file for `i386` in musl-libc: `src/internal/i386/syscall.s`. Let's verify that first. Since there is also a file `src/misc/syscall.c` the name might be different though. Four files have `syscall` in the file name:

- `__syscall_cp.o`
- `syscall_cp.o`
- `syscall.o`
- `syscall_ret.o`

Querying those files using `nm` gave:

```
$ nm -s $(ls |grep syscall)

__syscall_cp.o:
00000000 t sccp
         U __syscall
00000005 T __syscall_cp
00000000 W __syscall_cp_c

syscall_cp.o:
         U __cancel
00000008 T __cp_begin
00000035 T __cp_cancel
00000030 T __cp_end
00000000 T __syscall_cp_asm

syscall.o:
00000000 T syscall
         U __syscall_ret
         U __vsyscall6

syscall_ret.o:
         U __errno_location
00000000 T __syscall_ret
```

Symbols with the symbol type `U` are undefined and therefore expected by the linker to come from outside (external to each object file).

A final `$ nm --defined-only *.o ../*.o|grep vsyscall` was what was needed to verify that those symbols were indeed missing from the `libc.a`.

So the cross-built `libc.a` what was faulty after all. Back to the drawing board.

I hope this description helps others to figure out similar issues and look behind the scenes in GCC.

### The saga continues

I was really surprised to see:

```
$ nm --defined-only ../libc.a |grep -B 2 vsyscall
syscall.o:
0000004b T __syscall
00000000 T __vsyscall
00000031 T __vsyscall6
```

but for the extracted object files the corresponding command (`nm --defined-only *.o ../*.o|grep -B 2 vsyscall`) would yield no output.

So inside the `libc.a` somehow `nm` sees the two symbols, but after extracting them they disappear? Odd.

Let's look for `syscall.o` in the `libc.a`:

```
$ nm ../libc.a |grep ^syscall
syscall.o:
syscall_ret.o:
syscall.o:
syscall_cp.o:
```

Whoa? So `syscall.o` exists twice inside the static library? Well that looks like it may just be the error cause we're looking for. And it certainly does explain why the symbols disappear. Likely the latter `syscall.o` overwrites the one first extracted when running `ar x ...`.

Confirming:

```
$ nm ../libc.a |grep -A 4 ^syscall\.o
syscall.o:
0000004b T __syscall
         U __sysinfo
00000000 T __vsyscall
00000031 T __vsyscall6
--
syscall.o:
00000000 T syscall
         U __syscall_ret
         U __vsyscall6
```

and looking into the musl-libc source tree after doing the 32-bit build:

```
$ find . -type f -name 'syscall.o' -exec nm {} +

./src/internal/syscall.o:
0000004b T __syscall
         U __sysinfo
00000000 T __vsyscall
00000031 T __vsyscall6

./src/misc/syscall.o:
00000000 T syscall
         U __syscall_ret
         U __vsyscall6
```

Copying the former into the `lib32/archive` directory under a name that doesn't collide with existing names gives more errors on other functions, suggesting other object files may also exist as duplicates inside the generated `libc.a`.

#### Which ones are duplicates?

```
$ diff <(nm libc.a|grep ':$'|cut -f 1 -d :|sort) <(nm libc.a|grep ':$'|cut -f 1 -d :|sort -u)
--- /dev/fd/63  2015-10-05 23:58:53.683804823 +0000
+++ /dev/fd/62  2015-10-05 23:58:53.683804823 +0000
@@ -131,7 +131,6 @@
 clogl.o
 clog.o
 clone.o
-clone.o
 closedir.o
 close.o
 cnd_broadcast.o
@@ -1115,7 +1114,6 @@
 __syscall_cp.o
 syscall_cp.o
 syscall.o
-syscall.o
 syscall_ret.o
 sysconf.o
 sysinfo.o
```

This way we see `clone.o` and `syscall.o` are affected as duplicates. Which indicates that some object files are missing altogether from the `libc.a` given undefined references to the following symbols:

- `__divdi3`
- `__moddi3`
- `__mulxc3`
- `__tls_get_new`
- `__udivdi3`
- `__umoddi3`

These names happen to coincide with the ones from the [Integer library routines](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Integer-library-routines.html#Integer-library-routines) listed for GCC. Which makes me think I am missing one library provided by GCC which to link. Like `libgcc`?! ...

I have package `lib32gcc-4.8-dev` which means I should have the required file:

```
$ apt-file list lib32gcc-4.8-dev|grep -E 'libgcc.*\.a'
lib32gcc-4.8-dev: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/32/libgcc.a
lib32gcc-4.8-dev: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/32/libgcc_eh.a
```

After the previous step I decided to set up a x86_32 version on Ubuntu 14.04 that was essentially at the same patch level.

I then compared the `libgcc.a` from the x86_32 machine with that from the x86_64 machine. They turned out to be almost identical except for the "symbol value" (in `nm` lingo) of a handful of functions.

Also, since the symbols were in the static library I attempted to link against the static library again. This worked only with `-melf_i386` on the linker (`collect2`) command line.

After trying to use `LDFLAGS` and noticing that those were also passed to `cc1`, I set appended `-Wl,-melf_i386` to the `CFLAGS` and now it worked. Brilliant.

---

As a side-note: I also swapped the `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/collect2` in the command line for `ld` of which `collect2` is supposed to be a wrapper. The error output was identical.

Answer (score 4):

In short, the `musl-gcc` wrapper script setup is not well-suited to use with `-m32`. I think what's happening is that the actual compiler is getting invoked in the default (64-bit) mode by `musl-gcc`, then the resulting object files are not compatible with the (intended, 32-bit) libc.

It may work if you put `-m32` in the generated wrapper script. This will happen automatically with recent versions if you put the `-m32` in `$CC` (i.e. `CC="gcc -m32"`) rather than putting it in `$CFLAGS`.

Update: As noted in the discussion that was moved to chat, adding `-Wl,-melf_i386` is probably also needed (due to flaws in the spec file used by the `musl-gcc` wrapper that don't account for `-m32` support) but still does not seem to be sufficient.

Comment: Interesting recommendation. This suggests I need to modify the generated `musl-gcc.specs` to get it to work. Let me try that and get back here with the results. Thanks.

Comment: I would just modify the `musl-gcc` script itself, not the specs. If you modify the specs, you would need to put `-m32` in the `self_specs` I think.

Comment: Putting it into the `musl-gcc` wrapper behind `"$@"` gives me the exact same errors as before. But when adding `-v` to `LDFLAGS` I can see `Target: x86_64-linux-gnu`. So I guess that's my problem ... still looking at `gcc -dumpspecs` and `musl-gcc -dumpspecs` and comparing ...

Comment: Asking on the musl mailing list or irc channel might be more likely to get you in contact with someone who has experience making this setup work. If you show me exactly what you put in the `musl-gcc` script, I could quickly check that for you here too.

Comment: other than the hashbang: `exec "${REALGCC:-gcc}" "$@" -m32 -specs "$HOME/bin/musl-32-bit/lib/musl-gcc.specs"`

Comment: That looks ok, but maybe try putting the `-m32` before the `"$@"`?

Comment: I posted an answer to my own question containing the final puzzle piece to make it work. If I can come up with a sensible patch to the specs file etc, I'll post it on the musl-libc list. Thanks for your pointers and also for musl-libc itself!